# How to monitor android app that already launched in play store?

Tags: android

I am currently working an android app that already launched in Play Store. This application, have a full dependency with the data (stored in sqlite in device and sql server). The data in client and server maybe different, because the synchronization process is scheduled, not real time.

The problem is, my application have some bugs when it already delivered to client. One of these problems made the synchronization process failed, and i cant figured out what is wrong in client side. My tester already tested it on testing environment, and it all worked normally (or maybe my testers are a bit sucks).

I'm currently thinking the ways that i can debug it remotely, or at least read the error logs remotely. or even export the sqlite from device, and send it to my server, remotely.
I want to do this, because i still don't know, in which processes that made my application produced these bugs.

How can i achieve that? Do you guys, have some methods or solution for this kind of process? Or maybe I'm in a very false development life cycle so that kind of problem happened?

Maybe the response will be various and subjective, but i kinda take it all, because i already googled it, and found nothing.

Thanks guys, please enlighten me.

Ps. Sorry about my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution once the app is running already. You have to package a tool with the app before sending it out to production.

As a solution you can add [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/), [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/), [Arca](http://www.acra.ch/), or [Hockey](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) (to name a few) and send out an update to your users with this monitoring library included.

Once your users update to the new version the crash reports will start coming in. Many platforms also have the option to track custom metrics so you can see specific information on how your app is running.

Just btw, if the app crashes on any user they can choose to send you a bug report which will then show up in your Google Developers Console. Just be aware that most users deny this prompt b/c they think that it will send personal information to you. The other solutions I posted above do not require user interaction and are therefore much more robust then relying on this method.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and yes you are right, most of user didnt want to report it if app crashes. One more question, how about the sqlite, i want to read the sqlite data of my app in android device, is it possible to do it remotely?

Comment: you cannot just 'read the sqlite remotely'. you can create custom fields in any one of those motoring tools and log data to that field. Its probably not a good idea to dump the entire sqlite contents to any of those services, but you can create so sort of logging metrics to help you understand what is going on. Perhaps logging the amount of rows or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/). It will give you **detailed** (it will even give you the exact line in which the code crashed with its stack trace) and **well-timed reports** every time your app crashes (it will send you an email and notifications right after the crash).

You can even simulate crashes in your development environment.

You need to set up an account in [fabric](https://fabric.io/), and then you can install [Android Studio's plugin](https://fabric.io/downloads/android-studio), after that it's fairly easy to configure it.

Below is a screenshot I took from one of my projects that crashed.

[image: Crash example]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, one more question, is it possible to read the sqlite from the device remotely?